# Error in devtools::install_github("Bioconductor/BiocManager", ref="ghost-binary-repo")

Tags: r, github, devtools, bioconductor

```
devtools::install_github("Bioconductor/BiocManager", ref="ghost-binary-repo")
```

getting error like this-

```
Downloading GitHub repo Bioconductor/BiocManager@ghost-binary-repo
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/Bioconductor/BiocManager/tarball/ghost-binary-repo'
```

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does `ghost-binary-repo` refer to? Do you really need the ref?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It was a solution that was proposed given that there were problems with `BiocManager` on CRAN, see [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9136957/). However, I cannot find any updates that they fixed the problem. I'm guessing they fixed it and removed the ref, but it's not clear...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this should just be a comment, but:

- [the list of branches](https://github.com/Bioconductor/BiocManager/branches/all) doesn't show a `ghost-binary-repo` branch
- the [Bioconductor forum thread you linked to](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9136957/) discusses problems with BiocManager version 1.30.13 and using the branch to upgrade to 1.30.13.1; however, the [version on CRAN now](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiocManager/index.html) is 1.30.15 (posted on 2021-05-11, the same day as the *last* post on that thread)

Comment: The only thing I want to add is that the release notes of 1.30.14 and 1.30.15 contain no reference to this workaround or the original bug at all. But yes, the workaround is likely not relevant anymore.